# How can I write a Rust function to find different characters between two strings?

Tags: rust

The order of the characters is not important but the count is. I mean `aaabaaa` equals to `6a + b` and the function is like math subtraction. For example:

```
fn diff(a: String, b: String) -> String {}
```

```
diff("aabbac", "accba") => "ab"
---------------------------------
"aabbac" = (3a+2b+c)
"accba" = (2a+b+2c)
(3a+2b+c) - (2a+b+2c) = a+b // -c is ignored
```

Comment: Your examples aren't nearly clear enough. Both `a` and `b` in first example have the `b` letter, so I'd expect the difference to be `a`, but that's really just a guess. How would that work with e.g. `baaabaaaa` and `baaaa`? What about `cd` and `dc`?

Comment: Please also show us in your question what you tried already and where you failed. StackOverflow is not a "write this code for me please" website. Thanks!

Comment: Sort of characters is not important, so ```baaabaaaa - baaaa = baaa```

Comment: @ademcaglin If the order is not important, why don't you simply count the number of occurences of each character?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz i am new to rust, so i don't know how to write. You might give an answer.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I know StackOverflow is not a "write this code for me please" website. But my question is about specific case(maybe it is not clear enough), but it is not off topic or broad.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code to the question. What is the problem with the code? Does it fail to compile? Is it not doing what you expect it to do? How so? Would be great if you could also explain this. And something else: please check your first example. Shouldn't the result be `"a"`? If not, I absolutely don't understand what your function is supposed to be doing :/

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt my code works expected, but i am not sure it is right way or not. Also i am sorry, result should be "a", you are right(fixed).

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @zrzka Thanks, i added my code to clarify problem. I want to learn a solution for the question.

Comment: @zrzka maybe you are right, i asked the question at codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual technique is to create a function that counts the number of occurrences of each char, like [`collections.Counter` in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter), and to compare these numbers for strings `a` and `b`.

The Rust standard library documentation contains a [snippet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) that does the job. This is an adaptation that accepts any iterator:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;
use std::iter::Iterator;

fn counter<T, I>(it: I) -> HashMap<T, usize>
where
    T: Eq + Hash,
    I: Iterator<Item = T>,
{
    let mut count_by_element = HashMap::new();
    for e in it {
        *count_by_element.entry(e).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
    count_by_element
}
```

Now that we know how to build a map `char -> count`, we just have to compare the counts of the string `a` and `b`:

```
use std::iter;

fn diff(a: &str, b: &str) -> String {
    let mut v: Vec<char> = vec![];
    let counter_a = counter(a.chars());
    let counter_b = counter(b.chars());
    for (c, n_a) in &counter_a {
        let n_b = counter_b.get(c).unwrap_or(&0); // how many `c` in `b`?
        if n_a > n_b {
            v.extend(iter::repeat(c).take(n_a - n_b)); // add `n_a - n_b` `c`s
        }
    }
    v.into_iter().collect::<String>() // build the String
}
```

If you want a "one shot" function, you can forget the `counter` function and use a more direct approach:

```
fn diff_one_shot(a: &str, b: &str) -> String {
    let mut counter = HashMap::new();
    for c in a.chars() {
        *counter.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1; // one more
    }
    for c in b.chars() {
        *counter.entry(c).or_insert(0) -= 1; // one less
    }
    counter
        .iter()
        .filter(|(_c, &n)| n > 0) // only if more `c` in `a` than in `b`
        .flat_map(|(c, &n)| iter::repeat(c).take(n)) // `n` times `c`
        .collect::<String>()
}
```

Examples:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", counter("aaabbc".chars()));
    // {'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'a': 3}
    println!("{}", diff("aaabbc", "ab"));
    //aabc
    println!("{}", diff_one_shot("aaabbc", "ab"));
    //aacb
}
```